# has anyone used PIN for ARM

Tags: arm

While looking around for "PIN for ARM" I came across [this](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/docs/cases06.pdf). However, I don't seem to be able to locate it. Is it even made publicly available? Has anyone used this or anything similar?

Comment: It probably won't be much help to you as it only support XScale (ARMv4, no Thumb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It used to be available at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pintool-downloads, but it looks like Intel pulled it between the summer and winter of 2012.

It's still available via the [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) though, at https://web.archive.org/web/20120618005139/http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/downloads/pin-2.0-5567-gcc.3.3.1-softfp-arm-linux.tar.gz